# Slice rows in R based on column value

Tags: r

I have multi-touch attribution data like:

```
    medium  conversion
1   organic 0
2   (none) > referral > referral > (none) > (none) > referral   0,0,0,0,0,0
3   (none)  0
4   organic > referral > referral   0,1,0
5   referral > referral > referral > referral   0,0,1,0
6   organic > referral > referral > (none) > referral   0,1,0,1,0
```

I'd like to remove rows with no conversions (like rows 1, 2 and 3) and I tried grepl but couldn't make it work.

For the remaining rows how to split rows so it ends with a conversion, e.g. row 4 will be organic > referral 0,1
and row 6 will split into organic > referral 0,1 and organic > referral > referral > (none) 0,1,0,1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with packages from the [dplyr](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) which is part of the [tidyverse](http://www.tidyverse.org/) made by Hadley Wickham. The [stringr](https://github.com/tidyverse/stringr) package (also made by Hadley) is really helpfull in working with vectors of strings. Another package [purrr](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr) is helpfull for applying functions t lists.

First, lets import the libraries and create data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

df = tibble(
  medium = c("organic", "(none) > referral > referral > (none) > (none) > referral", "(none)", "organic > referral > referral", "referral > referral > referral > referral", "organic > referral > referral > (none) > referral"),
  conversion = c("0", "0,0,0,0,0,0", "0", "0,1,0", "0,0,1,0", "0,1,0,1,0")
)
```

You probably have the data as strings while a list represention would be much easier to work with. The following code converts the strings to lists by splitting on ">" or "," (resp. for medium and conversion). Also read upon the [`%>%`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html) which is really handy for working with data frames. After converting the strings to lists the conversion column can be made boolean by mapping the `==` operator on each row.

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(medium = str_split(medium, ">"), 
         conversion = str_split(conversion, ","), 
         conversion = map(conversion, `==`, "1"))
```

Removing the items after the first conversion is now a matter of simple indexing. A little magic is done with `dplyr::lag` and `cumsum` to get a boolean list that indicates all the steps before and during conversion. Then `map` is used to get (using the `[` operator) all the mediums by boolean indexing with `no_conversion_yet`.

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(no_conversion_yet = map(conversion, function(x) dplyr::lag(cumsum(x) < 1, default=TRUE))) %>%
  mutate(medium = map(no_conversion_yet, medium, `[`))
```

Filtering the rows that do not have a conversion is now easy. Simple remove all the rows that do not have any `TRUE` value in the conversion column.

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(any_conversion = map_lgl(conversion, any)) %>%
  filter(any_conversion)
```

Voila, life made easy by the superb packages of Hadley Wickham! (Also check his [paper](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf).)

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed reply. Probably I'm not doing something properly, but I get Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: object 'conversion' of mode 'function' was not found. for the last part. Can you please take a look again?

Comment: I tested it and there was indeed a typo in the last code block. I have changed it and also took the change to improve the code by using `map` and `map_lgl` from the purrr package instead of lapply and mapply.